# SQL Server - check input parameter for null or zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure for sql server 2008 like this:

```
create procedure test_proc
@someval int,
@id int
as
update some_table
set some_column = ISNULL(@someval, some_column)
where id = @id
go
```

If the parameter `@someval` is `NULL`, this SP will just use the existing value in `some_column`.

Now I want to change this behaviour such that if value for `@someval` is `0`, a `NULL` is stored in `some_column` otherwise it behave just the way it is doing now.
So I am looking for something like:

```
if @someval == 0
set some_column = NULL
else
set some_column = ISNULL(@someval, some_column)
```

I don't have the option to create a varchar @sql variable and call sq_executesql on it (at least that is the last thing I want to do). Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `CASE` expression. Something like this:

```
update some_table
set some_column = CASE WHEN @someval = 0 THEN NULL
                       WHEN @someval IS NULL THEN somcolumn  
                       ELSE @someval -- the default is null if you didn't 
                                     -- specified one
                  END
where id = @id
```

Comment: Thanks. That was quick and very helpful.

Comment: Except that this code doesn't do the same job at all - if `@someval` is not `0` or `NULL`, this sets `some_column` to `NULL` (Did you intend to have `ELSE @someval` in your `CASE` expression?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes, you are right, because the default value for `ELSE` is `NULL` since he didn't provide one.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
create procedure test_proc
@someval int,
@id int
as
update some_table
set some_column = CASE 
        WHEN @someval = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE ISNULL(@someval, some_column) END
where id = @id
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a *really* bad idea - I'd suggest that if someone wants to store a `NULL`, they really *shouldn't* have to pass some other magical value to cause it to happen. However, let's show how it can be done:

```
update some_table
set some_column = CASE WHEN @someVal = 0 THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(@someval, some_column) END
where id = @id
```

Given the simplicity of the stored procedure in your question, of course, the whole matter can be cleared up by not *calling* the stored procedure if you don't want to alter `some_column`. I'd imagine that your real procedure is more complex. Instead, what I'd do is have:

```
create procedure test_proc
@someval int,
@someval_specified bit,
@id int
as
update some_table
set some_column = CASE WHEN @someval_specified = 1 THEN @someval ELSE some_column END
where id = @id
```

And now `NULL` means `NULL`, `0` means `0`, etc.